# Magnet doesn't drag and snap Adobe Reader

Tags: macos, adobe-reader

I have this handy app Magnet (2.11.0) on my Mac (13.3.1 (22E261)). However, it doesn't quite work for the windows of Adobe Reader (2023.001.20143). I can still drag those windows around, but they don't snap into place anymore. I think I recall that this stopped working with Adobe Reader getting a new fresh look.

Adobe Reader seems to be the only app Magnet doesn't work with (at least in my collection).

Any idea how to get these two to work together again?